Did Empedocles and Democritus develop physics while Aristotle developed biology?
One author, Givón (2013), argued that Aristotle turned biology into a functionalist science, against Empedocles and Democritus who where trying to turn it into a structuralist science.

The second line, concerning the functional motivation for the structure of individual bodily organs, harkens back to Aristotle, the founder of empirical biology. Two structuralist schools dominated Greek biological thought prior to Aristotle's, both seeking to understand bioorganisms like inorganic matter. Empedocles proposed to explain organisms by their component elements, while Democritus opted for understanding them through their component parts-- their structure. (...) Ever since Aristotle, structuralism--the idea that structure is autonomous, arbitrary and requires no 'external' explanation; or worse, that structure somehow explains itself--has been a dead issue in biology, a discipline where common-sense functionalism is taken for granted like mother's milk.

But from my understanding of biology and physics, and my knowledge of these philosophers, it seems to me Aristotle simply developed biology, while the other two developed physics.
Did Empedocles and Democritus developed physics while Aristotle developed biology?
References:
Givón, T.. "On the Intellectual Roots of Functionalism in Linguistics". Functional Approaches to Language, edited by Shannon Bischoff and Carmen Jany, Berlin, Boston: De Gruyter Mouton, 2013, pp. 9-30. https://doi.org/10.1515/9783110285321.9

They do not depeloped physics in a modern sense: they developed some principles to explain natural phenomena.

See Fragments of Empedocles: browsing some of them can give you a "feeling" about E's approach to natural phenomena. And see Empedocles.

This is false.
Both Empedocles and Democritus wrote on a vast range of subjects but only fragments have come down to us. Democritus is known alongside with Leucippus as the Greek fathers of atomism and many make the mistake that atoms are fundamental and hence they are responsible for physics.
But atoms aren't the only fundamental quantity, fields are also fundamental and this is, essentially the theory of continua. Democritus & Leucippus were not responsible for this. Instead it is the line of inquiry followed by Thales, Empedocles and Aristotle.
Aristotle also wrote on a vast number of subjects,one of which was physics. He devoted two books on fundamental theoretical physics, his Physics and Metaphysics.
Many modern physicists bash Aristotle for leading physics astray but this is just wrong-headed and is really about the moderns bashing Christianity. Aristotle wrote very clearly and discursively, any open-minded physicist reading Aristotle would recognise what he was doing as physics. Most modern physicists don't bother and just go on hearsay.

The only physics developed before around 1200 AD was statics, fluid statics, and optics, and that was all done by mathematicians like Euclid and Archimedes, not philosophers. Aristotle wrote a book on physics, but nothing in it would be recognized as physics today. It would be better categorized as natural history (basically, just describing what is seen) along with some wild unsupported theories about causation.
The work of Empedocles and Democritus has even less to recommend it than Aristotle in physics. Aristotle's notions of teleological motion of inanimate matter were actually a less fantastic version of Empedocles. Aristotle at least removed the superfluous emotions that Empedocles attributed to dead matter. I only know Democritus as an early atomist, but early atomism was all wrong about practically everything, and more importantly, it had no predictive power at all. It was more of an explanatory template than a theory.
By contrast, Classical mathematicians developed the law of the lever, laws of reflection and refraction, and reasonable approximations to the law of the inclined plane and the law of buoyancy. They used these laws in some pretty impressive reasoning such as Archimedes' treatises on finding the center of gravity.
The Classical philosophers were aware of magnetism and static electricity, but those were topics of natural history, and most of what was said about those things was wrong until a treatise written around 1200 AD by an unknown scholar named Peregrinus (probably a military engineer in the Crusades). That treatise would arguably be the beginning of Medieval science except that it was forgotten for several centuries. The next people in recorded history that did anything like modern physics were in the 1600s. The most important ones were Robert Norman (magnetism), William Gilbert (magnetism and static electricity), and Galileo Galilei (lots of stuff). I'm leaving out Copernicus because his influence was in astronomy.

Maybe then I should re-formulate my question: as of "bioorganisms like inorganic matter", does Aristotle work roughly more belong to what we might call biology, and Empedocles and Democritus work more to what we might call physics?

@Starckman, I think the only surviving work of Empedocles is a poem where he develops an ontology beginning with chaos and ending with life forms as we know it, so he didn't restrict himself to non-living matter. Democritus is known for atomism, which I guess would be comparable to physics.
